# Makefile not linking the necessary .hpp files

Tags: c++, makefile

I need to compile a C++ project which is going to use external libraries and headers from the project for linear programming COIN-OR. It contains two .cpp files. The main file, main-farmer, depends on pm.h.

pm.h has all the *include* lines main-farmer needs to use to call in the COIN-OR functions. This is is the code of pm.h:

```
#include "ClpSimplex.hpp"
#include "CoinHelperFunctions.hpp"
#include "CoinTime.hpp"
#include "CoinBuild.hpp"
#include "CoinModel.hpp"
```

I have a makefile provided by my teacher and modified to fit my own needs, but whenever I try to compile the project by running my Makefile I get the same error:

> In file included from main-farmer.cpp:5:0: pm.h:14:26: fatal error:
>   ClpSimplex.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [main-farmer.o] Error 1

This is the Makefile:

```
#
P=farmer
#

EXE=$(P)
OBJS=main-farmer.o model-farmer.o param-farmer.o pm.h

ADDLIBS=-D.
ADDINCFLAGS=-I.

SRCDIR=~/coin-projects

########## 


CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wimplicit -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion
CXXLINKFLAGS=-Wl,--rpath -Wl,/installed/CoinAll/lib
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-03 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wimplicit -Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall


COININCDIR=/installed/CoinAll/include/coin

#  COIN-OR libs
COINLIBDIR=/installed/CoinAll/lib

#  Clp
LIBS=-L$(COINLIBDIR) -lCbc -lCgl -lOsiClp -lOsi -lClp -lCoinUtils -lm \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/cgl_addlibs.txt` \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/clp_addlibs.txt` \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/coinutils_addlibs.txt` 



CLEANFILES=\
addBits.o addBits \
addColumns.o addColumns \
addRows.o addRows \
decompose.o decompose \
defaults.o defaults \
driver2.o driver2 \
driver.o driver \
driverC.o driverC \
dualCuts.o dualCuts \
ekk.o ekk \
ekk_interface.o ekk_interface \
hello.o hello \
makeDual.o makeDual \
minimum.o minimum \
network.o network \
piece.o piece \
rowColumn.o rowColumn \
sprint2.o sprint2 \
sprint.o sprint \
testBarrier.o testBarrier \
testBasis.o testBasis \
testGub2.o testGub2 \
testGub.o testGub \
testQP.o testQP \
useVolume.o useVolume

# Part 3
#

all: $(EXE)

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c .o .obj

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    bla=;
    for file in $(OBJS); do bla="$$bla `$(CYGPATH_W) $$file`"; done; \
    $(CXX) $(CXXLINKFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $$bla $(ADDLIBS) $(LIBS)

####
########
############
########
####


clean:
    rm -rf $(CLEANFILES)
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.cpp.obj:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.c.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
```

Note: ClpSimplex.hpp lives in the directory specified as COININCDIR.

Comment: Where does the `ClpSimplex.hpp` file live? You need to tell your compiler about that path (using `-I` or similar).

Comment: That looks pretty clumsy `for file in $(OBJS); do bla="$$bla \`$(CYGPATH_W) $$file\`"; done;` :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, this makefile is fairly awful.

Comment: `.cpp.o:` type rules are a bit old style. If you are using Gnu-make then you should be using `%o: %cpp` it is more powerful and easier to use.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit my post to say ClpSimplex.hpp lives in the directory specified as COININCDIR.

Comment: which `g++` are you using? If all tools are cygwin then you do not need `cygpath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Makefile defines `COININCDIR` which probably points to the parent directory of your .hpp headers. Those need to be found by the compiler, and as the variable is not used, it explains why they are not found.
If you add -I$(COININCDIR) to `CXXFLAGS`, the compiler will be able to locate them.